# Problems with mapping relationship in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I've got the following domain models (pseudo):

```
public class Camera {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Display {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SetupGroup {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CameraDisplayMap> Mappings { get; set; }
}

public class CameraDisplayMap {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Camera Camera { get; set; }
    public Display Display { get; set; }
}
```

which should get mapped the following way:

```
[Cameras]
Id (primary key)

[Displays]
Id (primary key)

[SetupGroup]
Id (primary key)

[CameraDisplayMap]
Id (foreign key to [SetupGroup]
Camera (foreign key to [Cameras])
Display (foreign key to [Display])
```

I am aware the data model is not ideal, but it's a requirement in order to support one of our legacy applications which handled most mapping etc. with application logic.

Currently, I'm unable to configure this mapping with the given relationship instructions from EF Code First Fluent Configuration API, or at least I'm not sure how to do it. I tried mapping beginning from `SetupGroup` using `WithMany`, but here I can't declare that `Camera` and `Display` should be mapped on the `CameraDisplayMap`. Starting from `CameraDisplayMap`, I'm unable to declare the Id as being a foreign key to `SetupGroup`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just an in-general recommendation.  This VS2013 plug in allows you to reverse engineer...specific tables...of your db.  I always run my pre-existing db schemas through it to see what it comes up with.   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: This also does reverse engineering..but you cannot do a subset of db-tables (it does all of them).   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

Comment: @granadaCoder I already tried deriving from the existing database, with the result of an awkward data model where all of 'em (Camera, Display, SetupGroup) each have a collection of CameraDisplayMap inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CameraDisplayMap Class should be like following.

```
public class CameraDisplayMap {
    public int Id { get; set; } //primary key

    public int? SetupGroupId { get; set; }       //foreign key to [SetupGroup]
    public int? CameraId { get; set; }           //foreign key to [Camera]
    public int? DisplayId Displays { get; set; } //foreign key to [Display]

    public virtual SetupGroup SetupGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual Camera Cameras { get; set; }
    public virtual Display Displays { get; set; }
}
```